# Web API is not executing a custom ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-web-api, modelstate

I am having a lot of issues trying to get my Web API RESTful POST method to validate a model using ModelState in my controller.

I [this](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/10/clean-up-your-web-api-controllers-with-model-validation-and-null-check-filters/) site that mentioned the need to create a custom filter inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute` and I cannot seem to get the unit test to pass.  When stepping through the code it never hits the `OnActionExecuting` method and `ModelState.IsValid` always returns `True`.  I have searched everywhere for code samples and tried them all and none of them work.  I have even referenced the correct namespaces as you can see in the code below.

**ValidationActionFilter.cs**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace OrbitWorksAPI.Filters
{
    public class ValidationActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting( HttpActionContext actionContext )
        {
            Debug.WriteLine( "ACTION 1 DEBUG pre-processing logging" );

            var modelState = actionContext.ModelState;

            if ( actionContext.ActionArguments.Any( kv => kv.Value == null ) )
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                    .CreateErrorResponse( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Arguments cannot be null" );

            if ( !modelState.IsValid )
                actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request
                     .CreateErrorResponse( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, modelState );
        }
    }
}
```

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register( HttpConfiguration config )
    {
        // Register routes
        ...

        // Register filters
        config.Filters.Clear();
        config.Filters.Add( new Filters.ValidationActionFilter() );
    }
}
```

I have this controller POST method:

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ResponseType( typeof( Contracts.Models.IInvoice ) )]
[ActionFilterAttribute]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post( Contracts.Models.IInvoice invoice )
{
    if ( !ModelState.IsValid )
        BadRequest();

    var newInvoice = await _repository.UpsertInvoice( invoice );
    if ( newInvoice != null )
        return CreatedAtRoute<Contracts.Models.IInvoice>( "invoice", new { newInvoice.Id }, newInvoice );

    return Conflict();
}
```

I also have a unit test:

**ControllerUnitTests.cs**

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task POST_New_Invoice_With_Required_Fields_Missing()
{
    // Arrange
    Contracts.Models.IInvoice model = new Models.Invoice() { };

    var config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Filters.Add( new Filters.ValidationActionFilter() );

    var repository = new Mock<Contracts.Repository.IInvoiceRepository>();
    repository.Setup( x => x.UpsertInvoice( It.IsAny<Contracts.Models.IInvoice>() ) )
        .Returns( Task.FromResult<Contracts.Models.IInvoice>( model ) );

    // set up the controller instance.
    var controller = new InvoiceController( repository.Object );
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = config;

    // Act
    var result = await controller.Post( model );

    // Assert
    var response = result as InvalidModelStateResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull( response );
}
```

And the model:

**Invoice.cs**

```
public class Invoice : IInvoice
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int InvoiceNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 50 )]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 250 )]
    public string InvoiceAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 250 )]
    public string SiteAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 10 )]
    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OnHire { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string InvoiceDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal NettAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal VATAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsCreditNote { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public float VATRate { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are separating the act of model state validation from the logic contained in your controller you should also look to separate the unit tests that verify their functionality.

If you are trying to verify that *any* sort of invalid model will be rejected by the filter then simply unit test the filter on its own and rest assured that invalid models will be rejected before they hit your controller action.

Check out the [Web API Action Filter Unit Tests](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Http.Test/Filters/ActionFilterAttributeTest.cs) for examples on unit testing action filters.

You can also remove the `[ActionFilterAttribute]` on your action method if you are adding it globally in your config.Filters collection and you can also remove the model state check from your action.